# SQL Server query performance - removing need for Hash Match (Inner Join)

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I have the following query, which is doing very little and is an example of the kind of joins I am doing throughout the system.

```
select t1.PrimaryKeyId, t1.AdditionalColumnId
from TableOne t1
    join TableTwo t2 on t1.ForeignKeyId = t2.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableThree t3 on t1.PrimaryKeyId = t3.ForeignKeyId
    join TableFour t4 on t3.ForeignKeyId = t4.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableFive t5 on t4.ForeignKeyId = t5.PrimaryKeyId
where 
    t1.StatusId = 1
    and t5.TypeId = 68
```

There are indexes on all the join columns, however the performance is not great. Inspecting the query plan reveals a lot of Hash Match (Inner Joins) when really I want to see Nested Loop joins.

The number of records in each table is as follows:

```
select count(*) from TableOne
```

= 64393

```
select count(*) from TableTwo
```

= 87245

```
select count(*) from TableThree
```

= 97141

```
select count(*) from TableFour
```

= 116480

```
select count(*) from TableFive
```

= 62

What is the best way in which to improve the performance of this type of query?

Comment: Have you tested the performance using loop joins to verify it is an improvement?

Comment: Should TableThree be aliased as t3? And the JOIN for TableThree, TableFour then?

Comment: @Martin - no I haven't, it's a presumption currently. I wouldn't expect this query to take a long time to execute.

Comment: @Tim - SQL Server also looks at cardinality when choosing join method. You could try `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` and look at the plan and performance.

Comment: @gbn - yes, sorry, now fixed.

Comment: @Tim peel: Is TableFour t4 on `t2.ForeignKeyId = t4.PrimaryKeyId` correct now? And `TableThree t3 on t1.PrimaryKeyId = t3.ForeignKeyId`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First thoughts:

1. Change to EXISTS (changes equi-join to semi-join)
2. You need to have indexes on t1.StatusId, t5.TypeId and INCLUDE t1.AdditionalColumnID

I wouldn't worry about your join method yet...

Personally, I've never used a JOIN hint. They only work for the data, indexes and statistics you have at that point in time. As these change, your JOIN hint limits the optimiser

```
select t1.PrimaryKeyId, t1.AdditionalColumnId
from
    TableOne t1
where 
    t1.Status = 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
          TableThree t3
          join TableFour t4 on t3.ForeignKeyId = t4.PrimaryKeyId
          join TableFive t5 on t4.ForeignKeyId = t5.PrimaryKeyId
        WHERE
          t1.PrimaryKeyId = t3.ForeignKeyId
          AND
          t5.TypeId = 68)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
          TableTwo t2
        WHERE
          t1.ForeignKeyId = t2.PrimaryKeyId)
```

Index for tableOne.. one of

- `(Status, ForeignKeyId) INCLUDE (AdditionalColumnId)`
- `(ForeignKeyId, Status) INCLUDE (AdditionalColumnId)`

Index for tableFive... probably `(typeID, PrimaryKeyId)`

Edit: updated JOINS and EXISTS to match question fixes

Comment: what is the "join T" part after TableOne t1

Comment: `Exists` gives SQL Server extra information: it can stop afer the first match, as opposed to `join`, where it has to loop through all matches.  For consistency, perhaps replace the joins on `t4` and `t5` with `exists` too. +1

Comment: @Andomar: the whole EXISTS shpuld be collapsed, and T4, T5 depend on T3 anyway. I wouldn't/didn't want to have `...EXISTS (T3 EXISTS (T4 EXISTS (T5)))`

Comment: @gbn - thanks but it's hard to tell whether it's made a difference. I'm now running both queries (before and after reformatting) on the SQL Server machine itself and they return instantly. I think the 5/6 second delay was from running it on my machine.

Comment: @Tim Peel: compare query plans and add SET STATISTICS IO ON too.

Comment: @gbn - your reformatted query is definitely better according to the stats!

Comment: @Tim Peel: thanks: the key is EXISTS which is a different kind of JOIN (basically, it short circuits).

Comment: I had a similar issue and this made a massive difference- Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

SQL Server is pretty good at optimizing queries, but it's also conservative: it optimizes queries for the worst case.  A loop join typically results in an index lookup and a bookmark lookup for for every row.  Because loop joins cause dramatic degradation for large sets, SQL Server is hesitant to use them unless it's sure about the number of rows.

You can use the `forceseek` [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) to force an index lookup:

```
inner join TableTwo t2 with (FORCESEEK) on t1.ForeignKeyId = t2.PrimaryKeyId
```

Alternatively, you can force a loop join with the `loop` keyword:

```
inner LOOP join TableTwo t2 on t1.ForeignKeyId = t2.PrimaryKeyId
```

Query hints limit SQL Server's freedom, so it can no longer adapt to changed circumstances.  It's best practice to avoid query hints unless there is a business need that cannot be met without them.

Comment: adding "inner loop join" changes the query plan as you would expect, the query returns in the same time (5/6 seconds) but is much less intensive on CPU/IO

Comment: @Martin - query cost relative between the two is 11% for just the standard join and 89% for the "inner loop join" - the loop join one has a Parallelism item at the beginning of the query plan. Looks like the loop join is just returning fewer rows at each join.

Comment: @Tim - I deleted my previous comment re parallelism as it occurred to me the 5/6 seconds might basically be the time taken to return the results? I often use `select @var1 = t1.PrimaryKeyId, @var2 = t1.AdditionalColumnId` to take this out of the equation when comparing performance. It seems like it is costing the inner join as being more expensive than it actually is then? Are statistics up-to-date on all relevant tables?

Comment: @Martin - yes, all stats are up to date. See my last comment to gbn